# Adding keylistener to panel in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I'm writing a simple game, and I have main frame with 4 JPanels placed in CardLayout.
Main frame looks like that:

```
private static JPanel[] panele = new JPanel[4];
private static JPanel panel;    
public GameWindow()
{
    super("Sokoban");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panele[0] = new MainMenu();
    panele[1] = new LoadGameMenu();
    panele[2] = new SaveGameMenu();     
    panele[3] = new GameScene();        
    panel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

    //((MainMenu)panele[0]).setSaveOptionState(false);
    panel.add(panele[0], "MainMenu");
    panel.add(panele[1], "LoadGameMenu");
    panel.add(panele[2], "SaveGameMenu");
    panel.add(panele[3], "GameScene");      
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


}
```

The GameScene panel have react to keyboard input. First I tried keylistener:

```
public GameScene() {        
    setFocusable(true);
    initWorld(); //Drawing on JPanel takes place here       
    addKeyListener(new Keyboard());         
}
class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter
{
    private int key;
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Tu jestem");
        key = event.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            Game.gra = new GameWindow(MenuAction.MAIN_MENU);
            System.out.println("Escape");
        }
```

That wasn't working... so I tried keybinding (simple implementation):

```
public GameScene() {    

    setFocusable(true);
    initWorld();  //Drawing on JPanel takes place here      
   // requestFocus();
    setInputMap(WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT, getInputMap());
    KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
    getInputMap().put(key, "pressed");      
    getActionMap().put("pressed", new AbstractAction(){         
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Spacja");
            //Game.gra = new GameWindow(MenuAction.MAIN_MENU);

        }

    });
}
```

It's still not working... I tried adding requestFocus and requestFocusInWindow() but with no effect. Any ideas how to fix it or to do it?

Solution have been found. In key binding I should write:

```
getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(key, "pressed");
```

insted of:

```
getInputMap().put(key, "pressed");
```

Comment: what is the superclass of GameScene? Component, JComponent or JPanel etc?

Comment: GameScene extends JPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Action`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513), you can bind a key (or combination) to that `Action`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513). For additional guidance, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) using either or both examples.

Comment: As you can see in my code I do almost exact same thing like in your second link. Difference is that I don't want to bind the buttons actions to key interaction. In mainmenu I change Cards but when i change to GameScene I draw Board and using keyboard input I want to move character(Sokoban)

Comment: I sounds like you want the bindings to change when the panel changes. Compare this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10015234/230513) using `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` to this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10186676/230513) using `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`.

Comment: It worked... thanks a lot. WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW));
```

Edit: For [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), "Each JComponent has one action map and three input maps."

Comment: I tried it... I got this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW InputMaps must be of type ComponentInputMap

Comment: I guess you will also need to use `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);` instead of `getInputMap()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you **really** want but if you want to simply react to key event when you're in "GameScene" card you should switch to this card firstly (to grab focus):

```
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        panel = new JPanel(cl);
        ...
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cl.show(panel, "GameScene");
```

Also looking at your code - consider using `JMenu` and/or `JTabbedPane`.

Comment: I haven't mentioned it becouse I thought it's obvious. show method is called as an action for button click. I'm creating full screen game, so I can't use JMenu and I don't want the tab names to appear.